# Не могу вывести список категорий из Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress

Я регистрирую CPT вручную через код, так же для него зарегистрированы категории

И у меня есть вот такой код для вывода из стандартной вкладки "Posts" в WordPress

```
<?php 
       $obj = get_post_type_object( 'my_tax' );
       echo $obj->labels->singular_name;?></a>
       <?php
            $all_categories = get_categories('hide_empty=0');
                            $category_link_array = array();
            foreach( $all_categories as $single_cat ){
                                $category_link_array[] = '<li><a href="">' . $single_cat->name . '</a></li>';
                            }
                            echo implode( $category_link_array);
?>
```

Но он выводит только из дефолтных постов категории, как переиспользовать его для вывода категори из CPT ?

Comment: Если Вы имеете ввиду какую-то кастомную таксономию которую Вы зарегестрировали для этого кастомного типа записей, то в аргументах можете так же указать таксономию, так как по умолчанию там стоит таксономия `'category'`.

Comment: @Simon я очень благодарен что Вы всегда отписываете мне) Имеется ввиду такой код?

$all_categories = get_categories('hide_empty=0', 'taxonomy=my_tax');

Comment: Только в таком случае аргументы должны быть массивом `$all_categories = get_categories(['hide_empty' => 0, 'taxonomy' => 'my_tax']);`, либо если вставляете как строку, то таким образом `$all_categories = get_categories('hide_empty=0&taxonomy=my_tax');`